# How to get TreeProvider.SelectNodes to return all data in preview mode like CMSRepeater does

Tags: kentico

if I provide the data query as properties of the CMSRepeater, the repeater shows all items (published or not) in preview mode and only published items on the live site.
However, if I try to pass a datasource to the repeater, I can't get it to do the same thing.
Is there some property or method I'm missing?

**Works**

```
 <cms:CMSRepeater  ID="rep2" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" 
        Path="./%" OrderBy="NodeOrder ASC" 
                MaxRelativeLevel="1" 
                ClassNames="MyClassName"
                SelectedColumns="Col1, col2, etc">
</cms:CMSRepeater>
```

**Does Not Work**

```
private DataSet LoadRepeaterItemsWithoutCache()
    {
        var columns = @"col1,col2";
        var path ="./%";
        TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider();
        return tree.SelectNodes("MyClassName")
                                .OnCurrentSite()
                                .Path(path)
                                .OrderBy("NodeOrder")
                                .NestingLevel(1)
                                //.Published(true/false)
                                //.CheckPermissions(true/false)
                                .CombineWithDefaultCulture(false)
                                .Columns(columns);
    }

var tnds = LoadRepeaterItemsWithoutCache();

            rep2.DataBindByDefault = false;
            rep2.HideControlForZeroRows = true;
            if (!DataHelper.DataSourceIsEmpty(tnds))
            {
                rep2.DataSource = tnds;
                rep2.DataBind();
            }
```

Comment: When are you calling these methods?  Your properties should be set in the `OnContentLoaded()` event or the `OnInit()` event.

Comment: @BrendenKehren I call them in the `OnContentLoaded()` method, after the `base.OnContentLoaded()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to modify your query a bit.  Your function is expecting a `DataSet` as a return value and you're returning an `ObjectQuery`.  If you want or need to return a `DataSet` then add `.Result` to the end of your `.SelectNodes()` method.

`.Columns(columns).Result;`

The other option is to return an ObjectQuery and simply assign that to the repeater and let the natural lifecycle process things.

```
public override void OnContentLoaded()
{
    //rep2.DataBindByDefault = false;
    rep2.HideControlForZeroRows = true;
    TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider();
    rep2.DataSource = tree.SelectNodes("MyClassName")
                                .OnCurrentSite()
                                .Path(path)
                                .OrderBy("NodeOrder")
                                .NestingLevel(1)
                                //.Published(true/false)
                                //.CheckPermissions(true/false)
                                .CombineWithDefaultCulture(false)
                                .Columns(columns);
}
```

Comment: Just to add to Brenden's answer, there are two parameters for thje ObjectQuery, Published() and PublishedVersion(). Published() - this one limits the set of data. It tells the method to return only items which have already some published version available. So, this one will remove the unpublished item from the returned items

PublishedVersion() - this one tells, what kind of data you want to get. In this case, the data of the latest published version. So, in some cases you may need to use both.

Comment: @BrendenKehren unfortunately that still only pulls published items, regardless of viewmode. For some reason, the repeater shows unpublished items in preview mode (desired) when handling the data, but assigning a datasource won't. I guess worst case scenario I can use the dataset only in livesite mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this way:

```
private DataSet LoadRepeaterItemsWithoutCache()
{
    var columns = @"col1,col2";
    var path ="./%";
    TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider();
    var datasource = tree.SelectNodes("MyClassName")
                            .OnCurrentSite()
                            .Path(path)
                            .OrderBy("NodeOrder")
                            .NestingLevel(1)
                            //.Published(true/false)
                            //.CheckPermissions(true/false)
                            .CombineWithDefaultCulture(false)
                            .Columns(columns);
     //If is in LiveSite mode, then return only published
     if (PortalContext.ViewMode == ViewModeEnum.LiveSite)
         datasource = datasource.Published();

     return datasource;
}
```

Before return the datasource, check if the site is in LiveSite mode. If true return only the Published nodes, otherwise return Published and Unpublished nodes.
I've not tested it, but hope it works.